# Auth0 + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, auth0

I am trying to follow the steps provided at https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs for getting Auth0 integrated into an Angular App.

Code I have is as follows,

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/login">
            <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Tweet
            <strong>Cloud</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right : 20px;">
        <a href="#/">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Fetch Tweets</button>
        </a>
        <a href="#/login">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-social btn-twitter navbar-btn" ng-click="authService.login()"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Sign in with Twitter</button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Despite my best efforts can't get the "authService.login()" to fire. Any possible suggestions based on common mistakes that newbies might be making?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: did you include the js?

Comment: @ZeissS If you are preferring  the demo example, I think you need to bind the authService to loginController object (this) otherwise you will not get the authService instance to call the authServce.login method.